# Template missing error in case of CSV format

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I am generating a csv file as a report. It works fine if model validations are passed. In case of failed validations I want to show errors on the "new" action view and keep user there until they correct errors, just like any HTML form. However since I am using format=>'csv' with my form I am getting template missing error when the user input fails model validations.

```
Missing template /new.html with {:formats=>[:csv],
```

I tried the following render in my controler but it did not work:

```
format.csv { render :template=>"new.html.erb"}
```

I even tried to add a handler in an initializer but did not work:

```
ActionController::Renderers.add :csv do |csv, options|
  self.content_type ||= Mime::CSV
  self.response_body  = csv.respond_to?(:to_csv) ? csv.to_csv : csv
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you redirect_to you new path in the controller?

```
redirect_to :action => 'new', :format => 'html'
```